# different php files on same mongoDB connection in php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to both PHP and mongoDB. I want to know if there is any way to run a PHP project having different files on a single mongoDB server-client connection;

I have created on **connection.php** file which is used for connecting to database but whenever I include this same file in different files, it starts new mongoDB server connection.

Is there any way that I can run complete project on single mongoDB client?

Answer (score 0):

You could use require_once("connection.php"); instead of require("connection.php");

Or if you use include at the moment you should use include_once("connection.php");

If you do it that way, you will be sure that connection.php will only be included once, so you will only have one connection.

Comment: But would that still create two instances of the driver? As far as I know (which admittedly isn't that far) there isn't such thing as application level variables in PHP except for within the Zend framework...

Comment: Ah, I understand. i was under the impression that he meant using different FILES with includes/requires (in one script). My answer is useless if he means what you're saying (and I guess you're right).